# Django test issue with dynamically created home page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-testing, django-tests

**Problem**

I'm attempting to create an app that allows for editable home/about pages using a very simple database model but am running into issues when attempting to test the most basic page responses. The issue lies within the use of `self.response = self.client.get(reverse('home'))` in the `setUp` method of the test but I'm new to Django and MVC design and can't quite figure out what the underlying issue is.

**Model**

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
```

**View**

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['home'] = Page.objects.get(pk=1)
        return context
```

**URLs**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

**Test**

```
class HomepageTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        home = Page.objects.create(title='Home', content='foo bar')
        home.save()
        self.response = self.client.get(reverse('home'))

    def test_homepage_status_code(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)

    def test_homepage_template(self):
        self.assertTemplateUsed(self.response, 'home.html')
```

**Test result**

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_homepage_template (pages.tests.HomepageTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/pages/tests.py", line 12, in setUp
    self.response = self.client.get(reverse('home'))

...

pages.models.Page.DoesNotExist: Page matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Initially it seemed like the issue was the lack of a `pk=1` object in the test database, but the issue persisted after adding a test page.

Comment: Did you add the testpage to the test database? Did you run this with `--keepdb`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I attempted to add the test page to the test database with `home.save()`, but perhaps that's insufficient? The original test did not have `--keepdb` but I just now reran the test with it and received the same error.

Comment: `objects.create` already saves the instance, so you don't need the `home.save()`. Why are you using the `pk=1`? Try printing `home.pk` in the `setUp` to see what is happening.

Comment: @gdef_ I'm learning as I go and appreciate the patience. I replaced `pk=1` with `home.pk` just now in the Views and modified the test to use `self.response = self.client.get(home.pk)` instead. That seems to have resolved the original error (thank you!) but now I'm seeing `File "/code/pages/tests.py", line 18, in test_homepage_template` ... `AssertionError: No templates used to render the response`.

Comment: @gdef_ EDIT: Apparently I overreached with the edit to the Views, because I get a name error with `home.pk` there. In answer to your question, I used it as a sloppy way to link the home page to its database object as I couldn't find a more elegant solution.